What are the existing applications of SSB with carrier and without carrier?
What are the existing applications of Single SideBand Transmitted Carrier (SSBTC) and  Single SideBand Suppressed Carrier (SSBSC). I need an explanation for the reasons for their use in each application.

please review your prior questions to see if they were answered or comment there on what is still confusing you (you have a lot of open questions still). Thanks!

This has really already been answered in the answer to the first point of your previous question. Also, this really sounds like you're trying to get us to do your homework, and that would actually put your question off-topic here: you need to show what you've tried, researched and where exactly you're stuck. You could for example demonstrate having looked into wikipedia and explain what about the articles you've read you did not understand. But it seems you haven't yet looked into this yourself!

This question is similar to: What are the drawbacks of using the phase shift method (Hilbert Transformer) for SSB modulation?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have actually done that. I am asking about the applications that are still in use.

yes, and Dan has actually answered which applications still use that in his answer. Please don't misunderstand me – I like that you're asking questions here – it's just that you've gotten an answer, but didn't seem to understand it. Then you posted this question on EE.SE, where I said, look, here, you already have an answer to that question. Then you re-post the very same question here… that's not a great way of working with the people answering your questions!

I don't see this question as a duplicate.

There is also vestigial sideband (VSB) which leaves a little carrier. If you have totally suppressed the carrier, the tuning of the audio in the sideband can slide and be off a little. This is the characteristic sound of SSB in amateur radio. But with enough carrier, the receiver can synchronize and pull out the audio content intact. I believe the old NTSC video used for American television (until digital TV circa 2006) used VSB for the video. If there was loss of sync, I am sure the video would come out really bad. A little bit of carrier might be worth it.
